# Карусель на jquery

Tags: jquery

На [сайте](http://binarik.net) на каждой странице крутится карусель из трех картинок.
Ширина блока 400px, а ширина картинок значительно больше. Соответственно они получаются сплюснутыми.
Есть ли  вывести картинки в нормальном виде? (желательно не увеличивая ширину блока).
Может есть какой-то плагин, которые сделает карусель из трех картинок, центральная показывается полностью, а крайние получаются сжатыми.

Comment: Добавте автоматическую висоту для картинок `.slick-slide img { height: auto; }`

Comment: При этом варианте картинка занимает всю страницу. Можно посмотреть на сайте, оставил эту настройку.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы картинки перестали растягиваться, у тега     `img` поменяйте значение свойства `height` со 100% на auto.

Должно получиться вот так:

`<img src="images/11.jpg" width="100%" height="auto">`

Comment: Картинка перестала сжиматься, но ее всю не видно.

Comment: А как вы хотите вставить квадратную картинку в прямоугольник без того, чтобы она не обрезалась и не растягивалась? Могу еще предположить вариант добавить в класс `.slick-slide` атрибут `text-align: center;`, высоту `img` поменять на подходящую, например 50% и добавить в css `.slick-slide img { display: inline-block; }`. Все это приведет к тому, что картинка небольшого размера, полностью, не растягиваясь, будет по центру элемента.

Comment: Отправил заказчика искать другие картинки

Answer (score 0):

мы в проектах используем jquery плагин [ImgLiquid](https://github.com/karacas/imgLiquid)

он автоматически ресайзит картинки под любой нужный размер.
Одна тонкость - использовать его не на событии загрузки документа, а при загрузке каждой картинки (изображения могут грузиться дольше).